# Searching for element in list, attaining the position

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list with combinations of lists, each list is containing six elements, i.e [(0,0,0,0,0,0)]. The values can be everything from 0-2. I want a function that can find a certain combination in my list and return the index in the list of that combination. I've written a small function myself which is only supposed to return True or False. My issue is that it doesnt seem to find the element at all, even though I know it's in there

```
def sampling_with_posterior(comb):
    if comb in combinations2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

What am I forgetting, some sort of whitespace or something? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Python's lists have a method that already do that for you. 
You can find the position of a given combination with the method `.index` of it:

```
def sampling_with_posterior(comb):
    try:
         return combinations2.index(comb)
    except ValueError:
         # perform best action for when the value does not exist.
```

As for your existing code not finding the value, keep in mind that a `list`  is not the only form os sequence in Python - you speak of lists, but your code shows a sequence delimited by `()` instead of `[]`  - in Python that is a `tuple`, not a list.  Either would work, but you have to use the same kind of object to search for containment (and also to look for its index).
One way to achieve that is to enforce the sequence to be of one kind upon searching - (and then, ensure that the elements inside of your list are of the same kind):

```
def sampling_with_posterior(comb):
     return tuple(comb) in combinations2  
     # The result of the 'in' operator is already "True" or "False"
     # Your 'if' statement is redundant.
```

And while you get that to work, let's talk more serious things: this will work for lists, but there are other data-structures that are probably best for you: if you just have to know if a combination exists - then a `set` is more apropriate. The search with the `in` operator in Python `set`s is faster, as it does not depend on the size of your data. But for using sets in place of lists, your combinaiton elements will really have to be tuples - not lists.  Sets are unordered, and there is no "position" for a combination in a set, though. Which leads us to...

And finally: why will you want that index for? To search for another peace o f data, in another list, which will have to be in the same order? If you have data which you have to associate with each of these 6-tuple combinations, you can use a dictionary, where the corresponding value to each combination, used as key, is already the data you need. The `in` operator is also fast, as in the case of sets, and no need to have an indirect index to retrieve other data, which would be hard to keep in synch:

```
combinations2 = {
   (0,0,0,0,0,0): "data associated with this",
   (0,0,0,1,0,0): "data associated with that",
   ...
}
```

(And no need to a separate funciton just to check if a combination is recoreded, as `in` already returns True or False)

Comment: hmm, well, I have a list consisting of lists, that is, 729 different lists, it is looking like : [(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),....]
When I try to call sampling with posterior i simply run:

print(sampling_with_posterior([0,0,0,0,0,0])). Im getting a false back, what am I doign wrong ?